# When I compile a program and cat on it, why don't I see 0's and 1's

Tags: go, binary

The question is simple: When I compile a program and cat on it, why don't I see 0's and 1's?

Comment: Why do you think that you would? What do you think cat does? How do you think other files that are not compiled "binaries" are stored?

Answer (score 4):

Because even though the code is compiled in to "binary code", `cat` just dumps out characters, which are 8-bit bytes.

If you used, for example, something like `od -x` you'd see the program represented as hexadecimal numbers, which is the most common representation today for "binary" data.

Answer (score 0):

Computers don't understand what you have typed on the source code file ( The file that you have compiled is called source code). You have to translate all you have typed into the source code into a format that computers can understand ( The language of the computer is known as machine code). Compilation is a translation process, which translate your source code into machine code. you are actually cat the machine code file, which is not a text file instead it is a binary file. we can not open a binary file using cat command.